# Why doesn't pressing the TAB key causes links on my page to be "marked"?

Tags: html, css, browser

I see that when I press the tab key, links on the page aren't getting focused.

I expect the TAB key to mark the next html control (anchors, inputs), like in any other site:
[image]

Is it a html/css issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure the default browser outline is being supressed, here is the code from the all.css file:

```
a:focus,
div:focus,
input:focus{outline:none;}
```

I have used this in some mobile websites, Android doesn't play nice sometimes with its element outlines.

**EDIT:**

Here is how I override the outline, straight from HTML5 Boilerplate:

```
a:focus                                             { outline:thin dotted; }
a:hover, a:active                                   { outline:0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it in my css, but when I inspect the elemnt with chrome I don't see this style... why?

Comment: That's a good question, I suggest it is because the outline is defined with the focus pseudo class.  I think Chrome is only showing the computed elements, not any pseudo class definitions.  I have updated my post to show how I override the outline (it will show up in inspect).

Comment: I don't think so, I'm 99.9% sure I have seen styles for a:hover and some other pseudo classes definitions before...

Comment: That may be so, I am betting its an oversight in Chrome's inspector.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed related to CSS. In your all.css on line 23 you remove the blue outline which normally highlights focused elements

```
a:focus, div:focus, input:focus{outline:none;}
```

If you want to have it highlighted, then you need to define some kind of styles. Or you just remove those lines and get the standard blue outline.